# Return a new array modified from a block/yield in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, yield

I have just started a full-stack developer course at bloc.io, and I am struggling on an assignment. I cannot seem to find the issue with my code, but I am also a bit unclear as to what the assignment may be asking for. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. The assignment gives the following examples. I apologize for the length of this post, but I wanted to be as thorough as possible.

```
  def return_bigger(array)
      array.map do |item|
        yield(item)
      end
    end

return_bigger([1,2,3,4]) do |item|
  item + 1000
end
#=> [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004] 

return_bigger(["cat", "hat", "bat"]) do |item|
  item.capitalize
end
#=> ["Cat", "Hat", "Bat"]
```

---

```
new_each([1,2,3,4]) do |item|
  p "Whatever I want! Item: #{item}"
end
```

---

```
def new_each(array)
  0.upto(array.length - 1) do |index|
    yield( array[index] )
  end
end
```

Then describes the assignment as follows:

Define a new_map function. It should take an array as an argument and return a new array modified according to the instructions passed in as a block. Feel free to use each within the method, rather than the array indexing we used above.

The first step in re-implementing map should be to iterate over the array:

```
def new_map(array)
  array.each do |item|
  end
end
```

The new_map method will be quite similar to our new_each method, but rather than just performing "side effect" behavior with each element, you'll want to store the return value from each block invocation in a new array:

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |item|
    # invoke the block, and add its return value to the new array
  end
end
```

When you've finished iterating through the old array, just return the new one from your new_map function.

From what I can comprehend, the assignment wants me to replicate the new_each method without the use of .map then store it in a "new_array" However, I am unsure what the flaw in my code is. Is there a reason that my code is not "yielding" the blocks I have defined? This is the code I have come up with:

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |item|
    yield(item)
    new_array << item
  end
end

new_map([1,2,3,4]) do |item|
  item + 1
end

new_map(["cat", "hat", "bat"]) do |item|
  item.capitalize
end
```

assignment:

```
 new_map should not call map or map!

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: [2, 3, 4]
     got: [1, 2, 3]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 new_map should map any object
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: [Fixnum, String, Symbol]
     got: [1, "two", :three]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

specs:

```
describe "new_map" do
  it "should not call map or map!" do
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    a.stub(:map) { '' }
    a.stub(:map!) { '' }

    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i + 1 } ).to eq([2, 3, 4])
  end

  it "should map any object" do
    a = [1, "two", :three]
    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i.class } ).to eq([Fixnum, String, Symbol])
  end
end
```

Comment: You made a very small mistake: you forgot to return `new_array` at the end of your method. At present, it is returning the receiver of `each`: `[1,2,3]`. Just add `new_array` as the last line.

Comment: even when I do that, I still get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Try this: `def new_map(array); new_array = []; array.each { |item| new_array << yield item }; new_array; end`. (Note the semi-colons are needed when code is written in comments and `return` is not needed when the value of the last statement executed is what you want to return (as here.)

Answer (score 1):

Two tiny mistakes: the fact that you are stuffing your `new_array` with original items, rather than with the transformed items that you are getting from `yield item`, and (as already mentioned by Cary Swoveland in comments) not returning `new_array`. As it is, you are returning the last computed value, which is the result of `array.each`, which is `array` - so instead of your computed result, you are returning the original array. This is why you are receiving `[1, 2, 3]` when you are expecting `[1+1, 2+1, 3+1]`.

Comment: ! Thank you! That did the trick. I have been doing this literally all day. I was beginning to lose my sanity.

Comment: Thinking that you are losing your sanity is beyond not having a clue, so you are making progress. Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |item|
    yield(item)
    new_array << yield(item)
  end
  new_array
end

new_map([1,2,3,4]) do |item|
  item + 1
end

new_map(["cat", "hat", "bat"]) do |item|
  item.capitalize
end
```

Comment: Double yielding might introduce unexpected weirdness if you have side-effects in the block.

Comment: Good to know! I didn't realize I just needed one yield.